# Any home router support Cisco IPSec VPN client?

Tags: router, vpn

I want to buy a router that support Cisco IPSec VPN client, so I can easily access my company's network without connected the VPN on my laptop.

Comment: Shopping advice is Off Topic on Super User. [Why it is so.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about in-built capabilities, but have a look at [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org) - its open source wireless router software, based on Linux, that supports lots of devices and can connect to various VPN setups along with other cool stuff. I bought a [TP-Link router](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-MR3220-150MBPS-Wireless-Router/dp/B0043GWGV8/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1335293968&sr=8-7) and put openwrt on it, now I'm using the USB port connected to a printer for network printing :) It's worth a look at and it can do lots of other cool party tricks (OK, maybe only for geeky parties) :)

Comment: I tried it, but it sucks. The VPNC have no web gui and need to connect manually..

Comment: I have to admit it's a shame there isn't a GUI for everything, although you can get the connection to start on bootup, see https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=11301